# Firebase/Swift: childSnapshotForPath access autoID data?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, snapshot

I am currently struggling with accessing other data stored in a path, more specific the data from a sub-folder. My setup looks like this:

```
userID{
    username:Andreas,
    gender:Male,
    age:18,
    footballTeams{
       Team1{
           name:My team 1
           matchesPlayed:3
       }
    }
}
```

So I am currently running this code to grab both username, gender and age:

```
ref.child("Users").observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot1:FIRDataSnapshot) in                   
      //code goes here..
      var username = String(snapshot1.value!["username"] as! String)
      var gender = String(snapshot1.value!["gender"] as! String)
      var age = Int(snapshot1.value!["age"] as! Int)                  
})
```

However, I want to grab all the team names stored in the footballTeams path, ordered like 'Team1, Team2, Team3' etc. So I stumbled upon "`snapshot1.childSnapshotForPath("footballTeams/Team1").value!["name"]`". However, this would have worked, as long as I knew the exact name of each team name-path, but this is stored as auto ID. Any ideas on how I would approach this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the right way when chose to work with `childSnapshotForPath`. You just have to get the `/footballTeams` branch snapshot and iterate over it to get each child.

```
ref.child("Users").observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot1:FIRDataSnapshot) in                   
      var username = String(snapshot1.value!["username"] as! String)
      var gender = String(snapshot1.value!["gender"] as! String)
      var age = Int(snapshot1.value!["age"] as! Int)
      if let footballTeamsSnapshot = snapshot1.childSnapshotForPath("footballTeams") as? FIRDataSnapshot {
        for child in footballTeamsSnapshot.children.allObjects as [FDataSnapshot] {
            print(child.value)
        }
      }         
})
```

Comment: That's also similar to another solution I tried, however both with my code and your code, I got this error: "Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'FIRDataSnapshot'".

Comment: srry. still learning some swift here and there. Let me know if my edit works. if it doesnt just get rid of that verification and go with `for child in snapshot1.childSnapshotForPath("footballTeams").children.allObjects as [FDataSnapshot] {
            print(child.value)
        }`

Comment: @askaale Nice! Does the edited code in the answer worked or you had to go with the one in the comment?

Comment: The commented code worked :-) accessed the values through an array from index 0, like footballTeamsSnapshot[0].value!["name"] as! String. Again, thanks!