# Firebase 2.0 - Reading data from FIRDataSnapshot not working

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Iv got a search bar that when you type it searches the database for that users username. The code that find the username work, but when i try and read a specific value it crashes. This is the code

```
func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

          Database.child("users").queryOrderedByChild("username").queryEqualToValue(searchText).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

        print(snapshot)
        print(snapshot.value!["first_name"] as? String)
        print(snapshot.value!["last_name"] as? String)
        print(snapshot.value!["username"] as? String)
        print(snapshot.value!["profile_picture_url"] as? String)
    })
}
```

The results from printing the snapshot are

```
Snap (users) {
12345UIDEXample =     {
    "first_name" = Bob;
    "last_name" = Someone;
    "profile_picture_url" = "exampleurl.com";
    username = bobby;
  };
}
```

but when i try access

```
snapshot.value!["first_name"] as? String
```

it returns nil and crashes?
Why if its clearly showing in the json that its returned that the data is there but wont let me exstract the value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your snapshot contains the value "12345UIDEXample" on the first level of children.

To access the data you are looking for you can use a loop through the children casting as a FIRDataSnapshot.

```
for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [FIRDataSnapshot]{
    let firstname = child.value!["first_name"] as? String
}
```

In this example child value will only return another snapshot of your object like so:

```
Snap(12345UIDEXample) {
    "first_name" = Bob;
    "last_name" = Someone;
    "profile_picture_url" = "exampleurl.com";
    username = bobby;
};
```

However you will be able to access the desired fields as you tried to previously.

Answer (score 2):

When trying to access the Snapshot properties use `childSnapshot(forPath:)` see another example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38055542/1751073).

But basically would look like:

`for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [FIRDataSnapshot] {
    let firstname = child.childSnapshot(forPath: "first_name").value as? String
}`