# Pull specific user from Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase

I've successfully managed to pull data for all users from Firebase, however I'm struggling when trying to pull data for a specific user based on the userId.

I'm successfully passing the userId into the function. I've tested this with print(userId).

It also seems that the userdataSnapshot contain the right data, however the "for user in userdataSnapshot" is looping through all the children of the user. First for "firstName", then "lastName".. rather than taking the value of all of these into the array.. feels like the error is with the for loop.

See output after the code.

```
// Get all data about a specific user
    func getUserdata(userId: String, handler: @escaping (_ userdata: [User]) -> ()) {
        print("UserId")
        print(userId)
        var userArray = [User]()
        REF_USERS.child(userId).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (userdataSnapshot) in
            guard let userdataSnapshot = userdataSnapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] else { return }
            print("DataService")
            dump(userdataSnapshot)

            for user in userdataSnapshot {
                let userId = userId                                                                     // pull content from Firebase
                let firstName = user.childSnapshot(forPath: "firstName").value as? String ?? ""               // pull content from Firebase
                let lastName = user.childSnapshot(forPath: "lastName").value as? String ?? ""                 // pull content from Firebase
                let name = user.childSnapshot(forPath: "name").value as? String ?? ""                         // pull content from Firebase
                let city = user.childSnapshot(forPath: "city").value as? String ?? ""                        // pull content from Firebase
                let country = user.childSnapshot(forPath: "country").value as? String ?? ""                   // pull content from Firebase
                let profileImageURL = user.childSnapshot(forPath: "profileImageURL").value as? String ?? ""  // pull content from Firebase
                let defaultHunt = user.childSnapshot(forPath: "defaultHunt").value as? String ?? ""          // pull content from Firebase

                let user = User(userId: userId, firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName, name: name, city: city, country: country, profileImageURL: profileImageURL, defaultHunt: defaultHunt)
                userArray.append(user)
            }
            //print("DataService array content test")
           // dump(userArray)
            handler(userArray)
        }
    }
```

Output from terminal

```
UserId
NhZZGwJQCGe2OGaNTwGvpPuQKNA2
DataService
▿ 9 elements
  - Snap (city) Oslo #0
    - super: NSObject
  - Snap (country) Norway #1
    - super: NSObject
  - Snap (defaultHunt) Hjortejakt #2
    - super: NSObject
  - Snap (email) christian.simonsen@gmail.com #3
    - super: NSObject
  - Snap (firstName) Christian #4
    - super: NSObject
  - Snap (lastName) Simonsen #5
    - super: NSObject
  - Snap (name) Christian #6
    - super: NSObject
  - Snap (profileImageURL) https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/shoota-179610.appspot.com/o/gghh%2F985188F8-1439-4906-8BDA-497EAEBDD99A?alt=media&token=359fa0b0-6a90-4393-ab11-a354437f701d #7
    - super: NSObject
  - Snap (provider) Firebase #8
    - super: NSObject
userArray
▿ 9 elements
  ▿ Shoota.User #0
    ▿ userId: NhZZGwJQCGe2OGaNTwGvpPuQKNA2
      - some: "NhZZGwJQCGe2OGaNTwGvpPuQKNA2"
    - firstName: ""
    - lastName: ""
    - name: ""
    - city: ""
    - country: ""
    - profileImageURL: ""
    - defaultHunt: ""
  ▿ Shoota.User #1
    ▿ userId: NhZZGwJQCGe2OGaNTwGvpPuQKNA2
      - some: "NhZZGwJQCGe2OGaNTwGvpPuQKNA2"
    - firstName: ""
    - lastName: ""
    - name: ""
    - city: ""
    - country: ""
    - profileImageURL: ""
    - defaultHunt: ""
  ▿ Shoota.User #2
    ▿ userId: NhZZGwJQCGe2OGaNTwGvpPuQKNA2
      - some: "NhZZGwJQCGe2OGaNTwGvpPuQKNA2"
    - firstName: ""
    - lastName: ""
    - name: ""
    - city: ""
    - country: ""
    - profileImageURL: ""
    - defaultHunt: ""
  ▿ Shoota.User #3
    ▿ userId: NhZZGwJQCGe2OGaNTwGvpPuQKNA2
      - some: "NhZZGwJQCGe2OGaNTwGvpPuQKNA2"
    - firstName: ""
    - lastName: ""
    - name: ""
    - city: ""
    - country: ""
    - profileImageURL: ""
    - defaultHunt: ""
  ▿ Shoota.User #4
    ▿ userId: NhZZGwJQCGe2OGaNTwGvpPuQKNA2
      - some: "NhZZGwJQCGe2OGaNTwGvpPuQKNA2"
    - firstName: ""
    - lastName: ""
    - name: ""
    - city: ""
    - country: ""
    - profileImageURL: ""
    - defaultHunt: ""
  ▿ Shoota.User #5
    ▿ userId: NhZZGwJQCGe2OGaNTwGvpPuQKNA2
      - some: "NhZZGwJQCGe2OGaNTwGvpPuQKNA2"
    - firstName: ""
    - lastName: ""
    - name: ""
    - city: ""
    - country: ""
    - profileImageURL: ""
    - defaultHunt: ""
  ▿ Shoota.User #6
    ▿ userId: NhZZGwJQCGe2OGaNTwGvpPuQKNA2
      - some: "NhZZGwJQCGe2OGaNTwGvpPuQKNA2"
    - firstName: ""
    - lastName: ""
    - name: ""
    - city: ""
    - country: ""
    - profileImageURL: ""
    - defaultHunt: ""
  ▿ Shoota.User #7
    ▿ userId: NhZZGwJQCGe2OGaNTwGvpPuQKNA2
      - some: "NhZZGwJQCGe2OGaNTwGvpPuQKNA2"
    - firstName: ""
    - lastName: ""
    - name: ""
    - city: ""
    - country: ""
    - profileImageURL: ""
    - defaultHunt: ""
  ▿ Shoota.User #8
    ▿ userId: NhZZGwJQCGe2OGaNTwGvpPuQKNA2
      - some: "NhZZGwJQCGe2OGaNTwGvpPuQKNA2"
    - firstName: ""
    - lastName: ""
    - name: ""
    - city: ""
    - country: ""
    - profileImageURL: ""
    - defaultHunt: ""
```

Comment: Maybe helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38137036/1457385

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use:

```
    let query = ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "userId").queryEqual(toValue: (userId))
    query.observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in...
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in the end. Below is the updated code. Basically the error was related to the guard let

I solved it after rereading the Firebase documentation. See "Read data once" section on this [page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write)

```
// Get all data about a specific user 
func getUserdata(userId: String, handler: @escaping (_ userdata: [User]) -> ()) {
    var userArray = [User]()
    REF_USERS.child(userId).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        guard let data = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary else { return }

        let userId = userId
        let firstName = data["firstName"] as? String ?? ""
        let lastName = data["lastName"] as? String ?? ""
        let name = data["name"] as? String ?? ""
        let city = data["city"] as? String ?? ""
        let country = data["country"] as? String ?? ""
        let profileImageURL = data["profileImageURL"] as? String ?? ""
        let defaultHunt = data["defaultHunt"] as? String ?? ""

        let user = User(userId: userId, firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName, name: name, city: city, country: country, profileImageURL: profileImageURL, defaultHunt: defaultHunt)

        userArray.append(user)
        handler(userArray)
    }
}
```